# Best method for finishing horsehair plaster walls?

Tags: drywall, concrete, walls, plaster, interior

I’m in the process of renovating my 1920s house, which is constructed of concrete block, with stucco siding. The living room walls were in rough shape, so I started scraping away what was loose, which was basically everything. What I’m left with is the original concrete block, with some horsehair plaster brown coat. The remaining surface is brittle, and scratches off with your fingernail.The wall consisted of a few layers of paint/wallpaper, what appears to be gypsum/plaster (the white spots), the plaster/aggregate scratch coat, and concrete block behind that. There is currently no moisture/vapor barrier on the outside, but we plan to redo the stucco properly. This means housewrap, rain screen/air gap, foam insulation, OSB, metal lath, then stucco.
From my research so far, considering the walls are concrete block, whatever finish I apply needs to be permeable since I'm in zone 4A; I need to allow moisture in the block to dry to the interior and exterior. As such, a gypsum based coating over this wouldn't work. I also don't need insulation on the interior since insulating on the exterior of concrete block to R-13 is best practice. My options so far seem to be:

1. Finish scraping off the plaster down to the bare block. Attach furring, then drywall. The air gap will provide space for vapor diffusion.
2. Clean up the existing plaster brown coat and apply a lime based mix, such as type S mortar, then a finish coat over that.
   Preferably, I'd like to go with whatever is cheapest. I'm leaning toward re-plastering the walls, since I don't want to lose any space putting up drywall. If this option is viable, I plan to use Quickrete base coat stucco mix, then Quickrete finish mix over that. Let me know if there are any flaws in my thinking and what my options might be. Thanks!

https://imgur.com/a/SVbIJNR